# AdvancedDataGrid Rows Invisible

Tags: apache-flex, advanceddatagrid, invisible

I have an `AdvancedDataGrid` that has ***invisible*** rows. I have tried calling `validateNow()` on the grid, but the rows remain visible.

I can however get them to render when I toggle a checkbox or a button, which somehow causes the grid to be redrawn. Is there a reason why `validateNow()` does not redraw the rows? I am very confused with this one.

[image]

*This is an example of what the grid looks like.*

Comment: I'm not sure I understand and I don't think your screenshot helps.  How did you make a rows invisible?  I was unaware that the AdvancedDataGrid gave any control over individual rows--only columns.  The only way to reduce the number of elements in the DataGrid is to filter, or replace, the dataProvider.

Comment: The problem is not the number of elements. The rows do not get displayed until after I make the grid redraw itself after I click a button...

Comment: Is the problem solved? I've never seen a behaviour like this. Are you using a `filterFunction`, have you set a custom `itemRenderer` or customized the ADG in any way? What does the `dataProvider` look like? It's kind of hard to guess the reason for this without seeing some code snippets or a working example.

Comment: I do have a custom `itemRenderer`, but I too have never seen anything like it. The `AdvancedDataGrid` eventually draws after I click a button or move a column that is part of the whole component.